# 500 on Google Cloud Run: The request failed because the instance could not start successfully

Tags: google-cloud-run

I'm doing load testing on an ExpressJS app hosted on Google Cloud Run, upon spike increase in traffic, there is a period where I see many 500 errors in Stackdriver with the message "The request failed because the instance could not start successfully." - which effectively leads to server downtime.

Seeing that this error occurs more frequently as the app scales up, I'm thinking this is caused by the Cloud Run load balancer assigning traffic prematurely to new instances, before these instances are ready to accept requests.

As I continue to run the load test, the instances are continuously and repeatedly killed and restarted, so there is no mechanism for recovery while the load is on.

I don't see any error logs from my NodeJS application, suggesting none of the failed requests actually reached my app.

What can I do to avoid these errors?

How does Cloud Run determine that a port is ready to accept requests?

Is it something I misconfigured in my ExpressJS app or can I somehow delay Cloud Run a bit before sending requests to a new instance?

Comment: When you say you don't see errors in your application logs ... can you expand on this?  Do you see any errors in any of the Stackdriver logging logs?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I see many error logs in Stackdriver of status 500 with the message "The request failed because the instance could not start successfully." But I do not see any errors logged from my NodeJS application.

Comment: When your app expose the port, is it ready to serve immediately? Or the app continue to initialize things before be ready to process request?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks for this pointer! I am running Apollo Server with ExpressJS and the problem seems to go away when I remove Apollo Server. So far, it looks like something is happening within Apollo that causes the readiness to be delayed after exposing the port. I'm still trying to pinpoint the exact problem.

Comment: This turned out to be caused by completely something else... My app is connected to a Cloud SQL instance, which has a maximum connection limit of 100. The auto-scaling, however, pushes the number of instances well beyond 100 during the load test, which causes instance initialization to fail, due to not being able to connect to Cloud SQL. I see now that this is documented as part of Cloud SQL at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#connection_limits_3.

Comment: You can use the `--max-instances` param to limit the number of spawned instance and save your resource

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because since the problem turned out to be something else.

Comment: This issue does bring up an improvement for your code. Check for and catch all errors. Log these errors to Stackdriver to help improve debugging in the future.

Comment: I don't think it's off topic. They did indeed have an issue with 500 errors with their Cloud Run service, they just didn't know the cause. Given Cloud Run's potential as a public facing web app, pairing it with Cloud SQL is a common use case, and this question is valuable since others may run into this issue too if they don't take care to stay within their Cloud SQL connection limits. @Hans, you should answer this question with your discovery that it was the Cloud SQL connection limit, and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you Matt, I posted my answer as you suggested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by a combination of Cloud Run auto-scaling maximum instance limit and Cloud SQL's connection limit.

I was running a small Cloud SQL Postgres instance (3.75 GB / 1 vCPU) which comes with a default connection limit of 100. (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/quotas)

By default, Cloud Run assigns a maximum instance count of 1000 for auto-scaling. During the load test, the sudden spike in request count pushed the auto-scaling to create hundreds of instances, which quickly exhausted the Cloud SQL connection limit of 100.

This exact scenario is documented for Cloud SQL: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#connection_limits_3 (it would be nice if this is also documented on Cloud Run, it did not immediately occur to me to look for documentation on Cloud SQL when this issue occurred)

The solution is a combination of limiting the maximum instance count on Cloud Run to a number that is tolerable, and adjusting resource allocation / maximum connection limit on Cloud SQL. The exact configuration would obviously depend on the expected level of load.